# BASH: "local var=${3-16}" meaning not clear

Tags: linux, bash, shell

Trying to understand some BASH script I encountered this line

```
local var=${3-16}
```

I understand the assignment part and the local part - my question is what does the dash indicate in "${3-16}".

If I try:

```
 $ maxi=${1-45}; echo $maxi
 45 <-- result
```

Please explain the meaning of the dash. Thanks

Answer (score 10, accepted):

When doing `${parameter-default}` (or `${parameter:-default}`), if `parameter` is not set, it will use the `default` value.

So in `var=${3-16}`, if `$3` is not set, `var` will be 16, otherwise, `var` will be `$3`.

You can check [Advanced Bash-Scripting Guide](http://www.tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/parameter-substitution.html) for more examples, and other substitutions.

Comment: See also [the bash manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Shell-Parameter-Expansion)

Comment: So `${parameter-default}` is not the same as `${parameter:-default}`, because the second one also includes the case when `$parameter` is empty.

Answer (score 10):

It means "unless the parameter is unassigned, in which case use...". (`:-` would mean "unless the parameter is empty or unassigned".) So `${3-16}` means "`$3` if it exists, otherwise `16`".